# Как сделать скругленные рамки/края в JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, javafx

[image: Круглые рамки]

Как сделать такие круглые рамки?

Comment: [Отметьте ответ верным, получите +2](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7025/291565)

Answer (score 1):

Для Вашего окна кроме, собственно, установки скругления углов, нужно сделать прозрачными и сцену, и подмостки (stage).

Также обратите внимание, что в вашем примере рамка толщиной в 1 px справа и снизу немного темнее фона.

Пример (без тени от окна):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 6;" +
                "-fx-background-color: rgb(45, 45, 50), rgb(60, 60, 65);" +
                "-fx-background-insets: 0, 0 1 1 0;");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 290, 120, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.show();

        // За верхнюю часть высотой 22 можно перемещать окно:
        com.sun.glass.ui.Window.getWindows().get(0).setUndecoratedMoveRectangle(22);
    }
}
```

Так это выглядит:

[image: Пример окна с закругленными углами]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте с помощью CSS:

```
.root {
    -fx-background-radius: 10;    
}
```

Comment: Не, цвет можно изментьь, но рамки не меняет

Comment: @whiletrue, но это же не цвет меняет)
Возможно, я не правильно понял ваш вопрос, но вы же хотите круглые рамки(границы) в самом окне приложения? Или вы хотите круглую кнопку Record, как показано на рисунке?

Answer (score 0):

CSSом. Вот только надо округлять края обоим **border**'ом и **background**'ом.

```
.some-node {
    -fx-border-radius: 20;
    -fx-background-radius: 20;
}
```

[javafx](/questions/tagged/javafx) [css](/questions/tagged/css)